# Why didn't I receive reputation for approved suggested edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I edited some question (suggested editing) and it was approved.
I still didn't reach 500 edits limit as I see on my profile but I didn't receive +2 reputation for that.

The last approved edit is https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8630446. It didn't give me the +2 reputation.

Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: Yes, you did reach 1000 reputation from suggested edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're at 498 edits. I'm going to blame two posts which were edited by you and then removed. There's no other possibility you've stopped receiving reputation points from approved suggestions.

[image]

---

You haven't received reputation points for **two** last approvals.

Your reputation points:

> [image]

The last edits:

> [image]

Also, visit https://stackoverflow.com/reputation. What does the bottom line say? I guess:

```
earned 1000 reputation from suggested edits
```

and 1000 is the cap - after it you don't get reputation points for approved  suggestions.

Comment: True, [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/330717) also show 491 approved edits as of June 23, so likely 9 more since then.

Comment: You are right ;)

Comment: Will I receive that +2 reputation once some old question I edited will be removed?

Comment: @Eliyahu No, you'll get these 2 removed too.

Comment: But why? Currently I can't receive these points due to 1000 points from editing limitation. Once some old edited post is removed so I loose 2 points I received for it's editing why would not came this edited post instead of that, deleted , and give me the 2 points?

Comment: @Eli Because nobody ever considered to be a big issue. You can post a feature-request though :)

Comment: @Eliyahu If an older post gets deleted, your reputation gets recalculated and the first edit which didn't receive 2 reputation because of the cap will be changed.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Previous commenter said it works differently...

Comment: @Eliyahu He is sure, of course. That's animuson, he doesn't make mistakes generally.

Comment: How could I know who's right? By nickname? animuson vs nicael? ;)

Comment: @Eli Eh, animuson is an employee

Comment: Ah, I see, he's moderator...

Comment: OK, some more question if I can: why currently I see 498 posts edited in my profile, not 500? I understand they were more, some of them were deleted. So 500 or 498 of them still existing. But why I see 498 while 1000 points for editing limit is already reached?

Comment: @Eli my guess is the first sentence of my answer :)

Comment: I don't think so. In the last period many old questions were deleted so I saw 483 etc edited posts on my profile. Then I edited again, reached 500, then some more were deleted etc. Now I can't reach 500.

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/3485434/eliyahu?tab=activity shows you've got 556 suggestions. Even accounting for a few dozen <del>deleted posts</del> rejected suggestions, you'd seem to have met the "1,000 rep from suggested edits" criteria and won't receive more.

Comment: Many were rejected too. I don't think suggestions on deleted posts are displayed in the activity tab